# Missing guns after raider attacks?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I was attacked by raiders and without even thinking I sent my two closest people to defend. The problem I had was they were missing their weapons? Do weapons get destroyed like in fallout series?

Comment: Did the people you sent to defend even have weapons in the first place?

Comment: Yes all my people on the first two floors had weapons

Comment: Well, I haven't experienced this yet with my weapons or dwellers. If this is a bug, it must be an uncommon one. All I can say is wait until the next update and see what happens.